# <form> only send inputs in the first view page (laravel-blade)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

i have a `<form>` in the first view and `</form>` in the last view. 
Looking at the DOM i can see that form tag is being closed in the final of the first view and i am only getting the input data of the first view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdA2x.png)

I´ve tried putting `<form>` as first and last tags of my frontend code but then the request don´t work.

PD. Sorry for my english.

I am working with laravel.

Thanks.

Comment: Post code, not images. Never images unless it is a design issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tags may contains another tags but never contain a lot of codes from tag. This is not sense.
If you want to form for multiple view, please use form in layout file not in 1-2-3 files

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. I tried it at the begining and i couldn´t, it would be another problem. But yes, this is the easiest and clearly solution.